# Complete response only after first function will set global flag

Tags: python, asynchronous, sanic

I have two function. First perform checking server service url-checking. Function are done as sanic-scheduler task and run every 2 seconds.

```
@task(timedelta(seconds=2)) 
def check_data_status():
    ...
    isProcessed = True
```

https://github.com/asmodius/sanic-scheduler

The second one is request handler:

```
def new_answer(request):
    ...
    # we should wait and complete response only after isProcessed = True
    response answer
```

The `new_answer` should complete response only after `isProcessed = True` from first function.

How I can do it. I am using Sanic.

Answer (score 0):

Sanic is using asyncio-compatible event loops, so you can use asyncio's built-in synchronization primitives for that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html. [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#event) seems like a good fit in your case.